# Creating an FTP User that can only edit one folder

Tags: wordpress, server, ftp

To backup a WordPress site, I am using a plugin that uses an FTP user to backup the site. For security reasons, I don't want to let this account do much more than just downloading new and deleting old backups from a specific folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85156/restrict-ftp-user-to-a-directory

I would restrict the FTP user to the backup directory where ever that is.